# Hijacking the realtime clock in linux

Tags: c, linux, interrupt, kernel-module

I want to write a LKM (Linux Kernel Module) that hijacks the realtime clock (interrupt 8). So I want the interrupt to be set to my function and at some point send it back to the old function.

I have tried to use the `request_irq` function without any success, probably because the kernel function that is there is not willing to share the interrupt (which is a good decision I guess).
I also tried to edit the IDT (Interrupt Descriptor Table), according to some pages I found. Non of them worked, most didn't even compile since they where written for kernel 2.6, and I'm working with 3.10.

This is a simplified code that I have just to give you the idea of what I'm doing.

```
kpage =__get_free_page( GFP_KERNEL);
asm("sidt %0": : "m"(*idtr) : );
memcpy(kpage, idtr, 256*sizeof(kpage));
newidt = (unsigned long long *)(*(unsigned long*)(idtr+1));
newidt[8] = &my_function;
asm("lidt %0": "=m"(newidt):);
```

All my attempts ended in good times with a segmentation fault, and in bad times with the kernel crashing forcing me to reboot (luckily I work with a virtual machine and snapshots).

So how can I hijack the realtime interrupt so it does my stuff? (And then send it back to the original function to get executed.)

[Here](http://cs.usfca.edu/~cruse/cs635s03/pgfaults.c) is some nice code to change the pagefault function on the IDT. I couldn't make it work, since it's also written for kernel 2.6. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497919/changing-the-interrupt-descriptor-table) question is also worth looking into.

To get the bounty please publish working code, or at least sufficient info to make it run.

Comment: In Linux You have no interrupt access at all. Try to find a suitable syscall in order to access the clock, or ptrace the date command. This should help.

Comment: What do you mean by this? What is the IDT for if so?

Comment: An example I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497919/changing-the-interrupt-descriptor-table

Comment: @icbytes since the OP is writing a kernel module, he has access to interrupts.

Comment: As far as I know, Linux doesn't use INT 08h, besides possibly on some very old hardware. It usually uses the APIC for that; see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14481859/149341

Comment: @duskwuff Well I have tried it on university computers, they has a few years on them. But when I tried to use `request_irq` I always got "resource bussy". Do you think that on newer hardware this won't happen?

Comment: "a few years" - The computers have an Intel Core v processor.

Comment: This feels like an instance of the [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341). Why do you think you need to do this?  There may be a better way to accomplish your larger goal.

Comment: @Zack I'm doing some research on security issues. I want to write various sanity checks that run periodically, and I need them to be run for sure (even if a rootki ran successfully), constant intervals are a nice plus, but I can work with "It will run sometime in the next X steps". Yes I know that with root access the IDT can be overridden by a virus just like I override it. But that's my 'larger goal' for now. To your XY problem - I need something that will run once within every X steps.

Comment: So, I am not a kernel guy, but I am certain there already is some kind of mechanism for executing tasks in the kernel at intervals.  Get your sanity checks running using that first, then worry about hardening it against a rootkit trying to hide its presence.

Comment: the very first sentence tells this. ok ok ok.

Comment: You can have a look [how the kernel](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.12.6/kernel/irq/manage.c#L1396) does interrupt management and reverse engineer it. BTW the link to the patch code is dead and Google cache still has it. This is code from 2003/4 (32 bit kernel as ASM is all 32 bit).

Answer (score 2):

This can help you : http://cormander.com/2011/12/how-to-hook-into-hijack-linux-kernel-functions-via-lkm/

Why not you simply hook a function that is call every x steps like you want and execute what ever you need ?