# Understanding IRQs usage

Tags: linux, kernel, interrupt

In the last couple of days, I've trying to implement a simple interrupt handler in C. So far so good, I think I've achieved my initial task. My ultimate goal is to inject some faults in the kernel through bit-flipping some CPU registers. After reading [this](http://www.webopedia.com/quick_ref/IRQnumbers.asp), [this](http://retired.beyondlogic.org/interrupts/interupt.htm#2) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481032/where-is-hardware-timer-interrupt?rq=1), I chose IRQ number 10, since it seems it is a free, "open interrupt". My doubt is: how can I know if this is the "best" IRQ to call my interrupt handler? How can I possibly decide on this?

Thanks and all the best,
João

P.S.: As far as I know, there are 16 IRQ lines, but Linux has 256 IDT entries, as clearly stated in `/include/asm/irq_vectors.h` (please see below). This also seems to be puzzling me.

```c
/*
 * Linux IRQ vector layout.
 *
 * There are 256 IDT entries (per CPU - each entry is 8 bytes) which can
 * be defined by Linux. They are used as a jump table by the CPU when a
 * given vector is triggered - by a CPU-external, CPU-internal or
 * software-triggered event.
 *
 * Linux sets the kernel code address each entry jumps to early during
 * bootup, and never changes them. This is the general layout of the
 * IDT entries:
 *
 *  Vectors   0 ...  31 : system traps and exceptions - hardcoded events
 *  Vectors  32 ... 127 : device interrupts
 *  Vector  128         : legacy int80 syscall interface
 *  Vectors 129 ... 237 : device interrupts
 *  Vectors 238 ... 255 : special interrupts
 *
 * 64-bit x86 has per CPU IDT tables, 32-bit has one shared IDT table.
 *
 * This file enumerates the exact layout of them:
 */
```